# Update PHP7 MYSQL PHP Extension

Tags: php, opensuse, upgrade, console

I need to Upgrade my Server PHP version to 7.

Is there a way to update in OpenSuse 13.2 to version PHP7 via the console?
Can I install a php Extension which allows me to use the following again?

```
mysql_connect
mysql_query
mysql_select_db
```

PS: May be you could help me on another question too? 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/34200270/1694342?sem=2

That's the Reason why I need to updgrade to PHP to 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered your other question in the other thread, and, you're not going to be able to use Magento with PHP 7 at this time. However, I'm assuming you're asking about a different PHP application since Magento surely wouldn't make use of these functions.

The short answer is no, because `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated and dangerous. Everyone should be using [MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (the improved version) now, as it fixes these issues. [Prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) should also be used. If you run into an issue converting a particular `mysql_*()` function call to MySQLi, just post a question to StackOverflow. There should be quite a bit of information on particular MySQLi issues on SO already.

But, as I posted to the other threat, it looks like you won't need PHP 7 yet, but you should still stop using `mysql_*()`.

Comment: soo "should be using MySQLi" still working in PHP7? Thank you very much. You saved me a lot of time and disappointment :)

Comment: No problem :) Yes, MySQLi should be used for both 5 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

The functions you are asking about have been deprecated for years, and no longer exist in PHP 7. See the PHP documentation for information on [choosing another MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for your application. (Note that Magento uses PDO so you should have no issues with that aspect of it.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know, that the function is removed in PHP7 but i got other really big projects which still run with these Functions. Are there no extensions or stuff to add?